# calling a js method from the body of html code and take in variable for method

Tags: javascript, html

I had this html code:

```
<html>
<title> Upload Malware File </title>
<body>
    <header id = "header">
        <h1 align="center">Upload Malware File</h1>
        <p align="center"> Please choose the malware file you want to upload.</p>
    </header>


    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="malware_upload.php">
        Select malware file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="file"required>

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div >
                <label for="mname"><b>Malware Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Malware Name" name="mname" <required> *HERE*
            </div>
            <div >
                <label for="uname"><b>Admin Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="psw"><b>Admin Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
        </form>
    </form>

    <form>
        <input type="submit" formaction="file_upload.php" value="Go to File Uploads" />
        <input type="submit" formaction="CreateAdmin.php" name="SI" value="Sign In" />
    </form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="submit" name = "logout" value="Logout" /> 
        </form>
```

Now I have this method:

```
function checkMalwareName(string)
{
   return ("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/").test(string)
}
```

How will i be able to call the checkMalwareName at the "*HERE*" marker in the html code cleanly and return an error if it is false?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the function to an event (`oninput`) of the element:

Change

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Malware Name" name="mname" <required>
```

To

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Malware Name" name="mname" oninput="checkMalwareName(this.value)" required >
```

Comment: Why did you choose to use oninput instead of onchange?

Comment: @Riz-waan, The difference is that the `oninput` event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while `onchange` occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed.